# Weird value of "Start Date" and "Next Bill Due" date in paypal subscription

Tags: python, django, paypal

I created Paypal Billing Subscription for monthly payment without any trials or initial payment. When I create Billing Agreement for this subscription I cannot customize "Start Date" (it's always 23:00:00Z of previous day) and "Next Bill Due" is in the past (the same day at 10:00:00Z).

What can be a problem?

My Billing Agreement is create in this way:

```
date = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
billing_agreement = BillingAgreement({
    "name": "Organization plan name",
    "description": "Agreement for " + request.POST['name'],
    "start_date": date,
    "plan": {
        "id": request.POST['id']
    },
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    }
})
```

Also when I open my paypal "Amount received" is equal to $0,00 USD so I think maybe problem is related with that.